# What is the advantage of using UI binder in GWT?

Tags: project-management, eclipse, gwt

Mention the **pros and cons** of UIBinder in *GWT*.

I want to develop a big project. Is it flexible to use **UIBinder** for my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UI Binder lets you write your display elements using a xml/html like language, and in a declarative way. This is generally cleaner than not using it and creating your display elements in Java code.

Also, if you work with designers, they will be much more comfortable working the UIBinder to modify the display of a page, rather than Java code. I would recommend using UIBinder if you can.

Comment: @Oleski can I get the better output by without using UI binder?

Comment: @YuPPie Not as fast as I know. You can check which features they support, but I believe you should be able to do almost the same set of things with each.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest advantage of GWT in the process creating DOM is UiBinders, also known as **“Declarative Layout”**.

- The UiBinder is a framework designed to separate Functionality and View of User Interface.
- The UiBinder framework allows developers to build gwt applications as HTML pages with GWT widgets configured throughout them.
- The UiBinder framework makes easier collaboration with UI designers who are more comfortable with XML, HTML and CSS than Java source code
- The UIBinder provides a declarative way of defining User Interface.
- The UIBinder separates the programmic logic from UI.
- The UIBinder is similar to what JSP is to Servlets.

Copied from [tutorialspoint: GWT - Using UiBinder](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/gwt/gwt_uibinder.htm)